# Adding folder to Document Set programmatically JSOM SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, document-set, jsom

I am trying to add a folder to the document set but the folder got created at the parent document library. Can somebody help me to find out what am i doing wrong ?

Following is the code:

```
var createFolder = function(context, list, foldername) {
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
        itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(foldername);
        itemCreateInfo.set_folderUrl = String.format("/Lists/{0}/{1}", "Documents", "Custom");
        var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        listItem.set_item('Title', foldername);
        listItem.update();
        context.load(listItem);
        context.load(list);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler()),
            Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));

        function successHandler() { console.log('Success'); }

        function errorHandler() { alert("Request failed: message = " + arguments[1].get_message()); }
    }
```

"Documents" is the document library and "Custom" is the document set in above code.

Thanks.

Comment: your error probably is in the context.load. Remove context.load(list); and try again.

And the set_folfer_url property is not necesary.

Comment: I don't think your URL should have `/Lists` in it, since document sets are in a library, not a list.

Comment: @ErinL it works, Thanks.  /Lists was actually the problem.

Comment: @Maddy, then please mark Erins answer below as the good one, everyone gets points and future searches will be better

Answer (score 3):

Your URL shouldn't have `/Lists` in it, since document sets are in a library, not a list.